# onCreateOptionsMenu() calling super

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I'm creating application with **OptionsMenu**. I found few examples with it, but everyone is using different place where to call `super.onCreateOptionMenu()` in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method.

List of different ways:

```
@Override // without super
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
  return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
  return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

What should I use?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do. First example will place your menu and only your menu. Second one, will add first super class menu. Last one will add your menu first. But, keep in mind that menus also have an order field, which will be taken into account at render time.

Let's say you are extending an activity that already has a menu, but you do not want that menu to appear but another one. In that case you would use first approach.

Another example: you are extending an activity that has a menu, and you want to add another menu. In that case you could use either second or last approach.

Answer (score 4):

The source for `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is as follows:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (mParent != null) {
        return mParent.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Where `mParent` is the parent Activity of the current Activity. If your Activity extends `android.app.Activity` then can just return `true` at the end and not worry about calling the `super`, as the default implementation will attempt to show a menu based on the parent Activity, which you probably don't want.