# Do I need an empty onCreateOptionsMenu for empty menus?

Tags: android

In my app I have some activities without menu items, that use the following override:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.appbar_menu_empty, menu);
    return true;
}
```

This works good. If I remove the override, I get the same effect on Android 5.1, i.e. an action bar with no icons.

So the question is: can I drop the override?

The documentation of Activity.onCreateOptionsMenu states:

> The default implementation populates the menu with standard system menu items.

What does that mean? Do I need to expect that Android comes up with some buttons I did not explicitly add?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove `OncreateOptionsMenu()` if you dont want to have menu items.

If you want to add menu items, edit the menu.xml file in resources/menu directory.

Comment: This is also what I experienced. Is there any reliable source that documents what the default implementation is?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs the method is defined in Activity class as below

> Initialize the contents of the Activity's standard options menu. You
>   should place your menu items in to menu.
>
> This is only called once, the first time the options menu is
>   displayed. To update the menu every time it is displayed, see
>   onPrepareOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu).
>
> The default implementation populates the menu with standard system
>   menu items. These are placed in the android.view.Menu.CATEGORY_SYSTEM
>   group so that they will be correctly ordered with application-defined
>   menu items. Deriving classes should always call through to the base
>   implementation.
>
> You can safely hold on to menu (and any items created from it), making
>   modifications to it as desired, until the next time
>   onCreateOptionsMenu() is called.
>
> When you add items to the menu, you can implement the Activity's
>   onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem) method to handle them
>   there.
>
> Parameters:
>       menu The options menu in which you place your items. Returns:
>       You must return true for the menu to be displayed; if you return false it will not be shown.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (mParent != null) {
        return mParent.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    return true;
}
```

also check this SO thread out [onCreateOptionsMenu() calling super](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303898/oncreateoptionsmenu-calling-super)

check the code for Activity class here http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.onCreateOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29

Comment: Thanks. You're now mixing `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onPrepareOptionsMenu` in your answer. Could you clarify that?

Comment: thats straight from the docs, it is declared and defined in the Activity class which is in android package `android.app`. i.e. super declaration for   `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Comment: Okay the link clarifies it. You're copying the "see also" content into the code for onPrepareOptionsMenu. So your answer has basically nothing to do with onCreateOptionsMenu because you looked at a different function.

Comment: Well, then I do not really know what your answer is trying to tell me. I already pointed to a part of that documentation in my question. The code is nice, thanks. But I still don't know if `mParent.onCreateOptionsMenu` adds items or not. So for now, not helping.

Answer (score -1):

see some sample code here where you need to show option in action bar menu

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_act_add_recipe, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

**/res/menu/menu_act_add_recipe.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_add_image"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_tab_add_image_white"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_preview"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_recipe_preview"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_tab_check_white"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_preview"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Comment: The question is explicitly about empty menus. Menus with items work just fine.