# Should #onCreateOptionsMenu return a boolean directly or call its parent class

Tags: android

Which of these two ways is the proper way to override `onCreateOptionsMenu` and why?

Like this, returning a boolean directly

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Or like this, returning a boolean from the parent method

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303898/oncreateoptionsmenu-calling-super)

Comment: In Android boolean methods are intended to give you flow control. If return true it means the event has being handle, if return false then the event is not handle. If the event is not handle then other events will be executed. By example in longClickListener if return false clickListener will be executed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onCreateOptionsMenu() calling super](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10303898/oncreateoptionsmenu-calling-super)

Comment: Do you want your parent to have a chance to do processing?  If so, call it.  If not, don't.

Comment: @GabeSechan Sure, but why would I want the parent to do any processing if I've already inflated the menu for the activity? I don't see the point.

Comment: @the_prole Depends on your architecture.  Does your parent process the menu to change it?  For example the base activity class in my current app adds a debug menu if its a debug build.

Comment: @GabeSechan I see, so in your case your inflating and adding an additional menu?

Answer (score 0):

If you manually inflated the menu with inflater.inflate(), this is fine:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```